# How do I delete all empty directories in a directory from the command line?

Tags: command-line, delete, directory

Say I have a directory named `foo/`. This folder includes subdirectories. How can I delete all the empty directories in one command?

Answer (score 154, accepted):

Try this command:

```
find . -empty -type d -delete
```

The `find` command is used to search for files/directories matching a particular search criteria from the specified path, in this case the current directory (hence the `.`).

The `-empty` option holds true for any file and directory that is empty.

The `-type d` option holds true for the *file* type specified; in this case `d` stands for the file type *directory*.

The `-delete` option is the action to perform, and holds true for all files found in the search.

Comment: I think this is the easiest way to do it so I am going to go ahead and mark this as answered.

Comment: Hey Bill, I tried to post another similiar question and it wouldn't let me because it said it was a dupe, so I was hoping you might be able to answer me here. Say I wanted to do the same thing as above but remove all directories whether they are empty or not.

Comment: The way you would remove directories, regardless of whether or not they are empty, type the following command: `rm -rf <directory-name>`.  This will remove the directory, along with all its contents including files and subdirectories.  The `-r` option means delete recursively, while the `-f` command means don't prompt before deleting.  If you want to be prompted before deleting a directory/file, however, replace the `-f` option with the `-i` option.

Comment: What if there were some files in said directory I wanted to keep. So, I wanted to delete all directories in /foo/bar/ but keep any files that might be in there.

Comment: It is possible to do this by using a pipe to feed the `stdout` of one command (e.g. `find`) into the `stdin` of the other (e.g. `rm`), however, be very careful since it may wipe out or delete files/directories that you don't want to delete!  For further information on how to do this, see the `man` pages for each of these commands.  To be safe, always test such things in a temporary directory before trying out on the real thing.

Comment: doesn't work in mac, only deletes the leaf empty directories, not the ones that contained only empty directories.

Comment: @joeybaruch On MacOS almost every directory you "visited" with Finder.app contains a `.DS_Store` hidden file, that usually stores your sorting/viewing preferences for that directory. Other apps may add other hidden files (e.g. Adobe Bridge may add a `.BridgeLabelsAndRatings` file), so perhaps those directories aren't really empty. Anyways, you can remove the `.DS_Store` file with `find . -name '.DS_Store' -delete` and then try again to remove the empty directories with the suggested command.

Comment: With the `-depth` option `find` can even match and delete directories that only become empty because all of their (empty) subdirectories were deleted. Try it out with `mkdir -p a/b/c/d && find a -depth -type d -empty -print -delete`.

Answer (score 14):

You can take advantage of the `rmdir` command's refusal to delete non-empty directories, and the `find -depth` option to traverse the directory tree bottom-up:

```
find . -depth -exec rmdir {} \;
```

(and ignore the errors), or append `2>/dev/null` to really ignore them.

The `-depth` option to `find` starts finding at the bottom of the directory tree.

`rm -rf` will delete all the **files** in the directory (and its subdirectories, and ....) AND all the **directories** and everything.

Answer (score 8):

```
rmdir *
```

Will delete all empty directories. It'll throw up an error for every non-empty directory and file, to stop those errors from cluttering your terminal, use

```
rmdir * 2> /dev/null
```

Comment: This is not suitable for scripting since it will exit with a non-zero status code but it works.

Comment: @the_drow how does it make unsuitable? By the way you can also use `rmdir * 2>/dev/null || true`.  (The *find(1)* way is better for scripting but for other reason: because it expresses better what you want to do.)

Comment: I often do this at `$HOME`. With an evil grin.

Comment: Because it will report failure if some of the directories are not empty.

Comment: is this faster than the find method? Has anyone compared the two?

Answer (score 4):

```
find . -type d -empty -delete -maxdepth 1
```

For if you only want to delete the direct subdirectories of `foo/`.

Answer (score 0):

#### Python approach

```
$ tree                                                                                                                                                                                  
.
├── empty_dir1
├── empty_dir2
├── subdir1
│   ├── file1.abc
│   └── file2.abc
└── subdir2
    ├── file1.abc
    └── file2.abc

4 directories, 4 files
$ python -c 'import os;empty=[r for r,s,f in os.walk(".") if not f and not s and r != "." ];map(lambda x: os.rmdir(x),empty)'
$ tree
.
├── subdir1
│   ├── file1.abc
│   └── file2.abc
└── subdir2
    ├── file1.abc
    └── file2.abc
```

This works like so:

- we use `os.walk()` function to walk recursively the directory tree. On each iteration `r` is set to current folder that we're accessing,`s` contains list of directories within `r`, and `f` will contain list of files in that folder. Of course if `f` and `s` are empty, we know that `r` is empty.
- first list-comprehension allows us to create `empty` , the list of all directories that are empty, based on the evaluation stated above.
- second function, `map()` is used to perform `os.rmdir()` on each item in `empty` list. List comprehension could be used as well as alternative.

As a script this would be as so:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
empty=[]
for r,s,f in os.walk("."):
    if not f and not s and r != ".":
        empty.append(r)

for i in empty:
    os.rmdir(i)
```

Comment: too complicated for simply questions :(

Comment: @nurulhudamustaqim  Depends on point of view. For a lot of Linux users who are used to Python this is actually very modest :) And besides its variety.  Modern system administration is not limited to bash or `/bin/sh` only and Python is actually more elegant language than those two