# Can a directory's mtime be older than that of file inside?

Tags: files, directory, find, rm, stat

I have this very silly and very basic question but I thought better to ask before I start pruning my NAS.

I want to delete all directories in which all files are older than 30 days.

For files I could have done:

```
find /path/to/files* -mtime +30 -exec rm {} \;
```

But this would lead to empty folders at some places. So I was thinking to rather delete all folders with `-mtime +30` but I am not sure if the `mtime` of folder guarantees mtime threshold for it sub folders and files.

Also, if what I am think is right, what would be the command for the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On linux directory modification time change if you:

- add a new file
- remove an existent a file
- or rename a file in it

If you change content of existent file, this is not reflected up to directory.

Because of this, I suggest to use these commands:

```
    find /path/to/folder -type f -mtime +30 -delete
```

this command remove recursively file older than 30 days and preserve folder.

```
    find /path/to/folder -type d -empty -delete
```

this remove empty directory if any.

Source:

[Directory last modified date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3620684/directory-last-modified-date)

[How do I delete all empty directories in a directory from the command line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/73709/how-do-i-delete-all-empty-directories-in-a-directory-from-the-command-line)