# Find not removing files in folders through bash script

Tags: 14.04, bash, scripts, find

I'm very new in bash scripting and I'm really stuck on the find method from Ubuntu.
I want to search in the folder `/opt/` for all folders to see if they are older than a specific date. If they are older the files in this folder should be removed (and the folder itself too actually). If the date is still too new the files should not be touched.

What I have in code:

```
find $BACKUP_DIR -maxdepth 1 -mtime +$DAYS_TO_KEEP -name "*$mystring" -exec rm -rf '{}' ';'
```

The variables contain these values:

```
BACKUP_DIR=/opt/
TESTDIR=2014-11-25-daily_testmachine
mystring=-daily_testmachine
```

If the variable `$DAYS_TO_KEEP` is 2, the date is 2014-11-25 and the folder name is `2014-11-20-daily_testmachine` the folder and its contents should be dropped.

What am I doing wrong that find is not removing/finding these files and folders to remove? I can't seem to find the error.

**Note:** if I execute the command with the exact string name of the folder in it the folder will be deleted. So I have something wrong in my format or naming.

```
find $BACKUP_DIR -maxdepth 1 -name "2014-11-20-daily_testmachine" -exec rm -rf '{}' ';'
```

To make things more clear I've made a screenshot to show the setup:

[image]

Comment: I don't see any errors. Are you sure that folder are older than `DAYS_TO_KEEP`? Command with fixed name, maybe works because `-mtime` is missing :)

Comment: I was exactly thinking about this last evening and turned out this was a big part of the problem! And minor tweaking of the logic. Thanks Letizia!

Answer (score 1):

My error was a logic error with `-mtime`. I thought my script was checking the names but `-mtime` checks for the date when the file was created.
So my final code:

```
DAYS_TO_KEEP=2
find $BACKUP_DIR -maxdepth 1 -mtime +"$DAYS_TO_KEEP" -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

I just had to do a `sudo touch -d "3 days ago" /filepath/folderToRemove` to make `-mname` find the folder **and** make sure the file was old enough to be removed.
So this final code removes all folders that are older than my variable `$DAYS_TO_KEEP`

Comment: Try [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/552649/can-a-directorys-mtime-be-older-than-that-of-file-inside/552902#552902), I think that can be useful to understand how find and file mtime date works.

Comment: Thanks for the link, this looks great to find out more about it!