# How can I delete all folders of a specific name without deleting Contents in it?

Tags: command-line, bash, directory, delete

How do I delete all Folders with a specific name (e.g. 128Kbps_Songs) without deleting its files

For example if I have directory "MP3_SONGS" with subdirectories "A", "B", "C" and each subdirectory has MANY directory Contains Film Name "FILM_NAME1", "FILM_NAME2", "FILM_NAME3" in it, In That Each Film NAme I have specific Folder NAme (128Kbps_Songs) in this "128Kbps_Songs" Folder I have That Film mp3 Songs Files

how can I remove the Folder "128Kbps_Songs", in Each Film_Name directory and Have to get these mp3 songs in that FILM_NAME..   ( Have to Delete 128Kbps_Songs Folder in all FILM_NAME without deleting the mp3 Songs in it, have to get the mp3 in FILM_NAME Directory..

```
MP3_SONGS (Parent Directory) ------ A , B, C

A (Sub Directory1) ------ FILM_NAME1 , FILM_NAME2
B (Sub Directory2) ------ FILM_NAME3 , FILM_NAME4
c (Sub Directory3) ------ FILM_NAME5 , FILM_NAME6

FILM_NAME1 (Directory) ---- 128Kbps_Songs (Directory) ------ FILM_NAME1 (MP3 Files)
FILM_NAME2 (Directory) ---- 128Kbps_Songs (Directory) ------ FILM_NAME2 (MP3 Files)

FILM_NAME3 (Directory) ---- 128Kbps_Songs (Directory) ------ FILM_NAME3 (MP3 Files)
FILM_NAME4 (Directory) ---- 128Kbps_Songs (Directory) ------ FILM_NAME4 (MP3 Files)

FILM_NAME5 (Directory) ---- 128Kbps_Songs (Directory) ------ FILM_NAME5 (MP3 Files)
FILM_NAME6 (Directory) ---- 128Kbps_Songs (Directory) ------ FILM_NAME6 (MP3 Files)

Need Files in:
FILM_NAME1 (Directory)  ------ FILM_NAME1 (MP3 Files)
FILM_NAME2 (Directory)  ------ FILM_NAME2 (MP3 Files)

FILM_NAME3 (Directory)  ------ FILM_NAME3 (MP3 Files)
FILM_NAME4 (Directory)  ------ FILM_NAME4 (MP3 Files)

FILM_NAME5 (Directory)  ------ FILM_NAME5 (MP3 Files)
FILM_NAME6 (Directory)  ------ FILM_NAME6 (MP3 Files)
```

Comment: If I understand correctly you want to move all "MP3 Files" from last sub-directory and then delete that sub-dir, right? if yes, you can use find command to find all files with `-maxdepth 3` and move them into dest directory and then delete the empty dir

Comment: Yes , Can You Provide the Code For That ???

Comment: Sorry For That :-(
in Simple - want to move all "MP3 Files" from last sub-directory

Comment: want to move all "MP3 Files" from last sub-directory

Comment: no, have to delete 128Kbps_Songs directory, but have to move mp3 file from in 128Kbps_Songs to last sub-directory,

if 128Kbps_Songs directory exits there only want this changes ..

Comment: could you update your question with the output of `tree MP3_SONGS` and make your desired result of that output by [editing](http://askubuntu.com/posts/574667/edit) that question? In [this link](http://paste.ubuntu.com/9773304/) I really don't know what you posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a simple script with following contents

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS= read -r -d '' n; 
do   
   dir=$(dirname "$n") ; 
   mv "${n}"/* "${dir}"
   rmdir "${n}"
done < <(find -type d -name "128Kbps_Songs" -print0)
```

Save it and make it executable using  `chmod +x your_script`

Now run it using `./your_script`

---

Here [`IFS=`](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/builtin/read) is done to preserve the space in the filename or path.

- `-r` -  disables interpretion of backslash escapes and
  line-continuation in the read data.
- `-d` - recognize delimiter  as data-end. Here it is emptying  out the
  `IFS`
- [`dirname`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/dirname.1.html) is use to remove the last folder name i.e
  `128Kbps_Songs` from the find command output.  (from
  `./temp/MP3_SONGS/128Kbps_Songs` to `./temp/MP3_SONGS`)

Comment: Thank You so Much ..... You saved my Time lot :-)

Its Workingggggggggggggggggg

Answer (score 2):

First move all MP3 files up one level by the command as following:

```bsh
find MP3_SONGS -type f -name '*.mp3' -execdir echo mv -v '{}' .. \;
```

- The `-type f` option looks for all **f**iles
- The `-name '*.mp3'` filter files which end with `.mp3`
- The command `mv -v '{}' ..` will be run for each subdirectory containing the matched file, which is not normally the directory in which you started find (action of the `-execdir`).
- The string '{}' specifies the current file name being processed everywhere it occurs in the arguments to the command.

**Note:** After running above command, remove the `echo` command to perform running actual `mv` command.

Then try to [delete all empty directories](https://askubuntu.com/q/73709/283843) (*128Kbps_Songs* directories):

```bsh
find MP3_SONGS -empty -type d -name '128Kbps_Songs' -delete
```

- The `-empty` : File is empty and is either a regular file or a directory.
- The `-type d` option as the same as `-type f` but this looks for all **d**irectories instead.
- The `-delete`, deletes the found file or directory.

See [man find](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/find.1.html) for more info.

Comment: in this i have one problem .... :-(

Some of FILM_NAME having Mp3 Directly in it,
FILM_NAME1 -----> fileNum6_1.mp3
Suppose i move all MP3 files up one level
i will get all mp3 out of FILM_NAME1 directory ..

in this case what should i do !!!!!!

Comment: @Chatcafe please run `tree MP3_SONGS` and post the result on http://paste.ubuntu.com/ and then give me the link

Comment: Thanks Brother for your Effort :-) 
its Really Helped me lot :-)

Comment: @Chatcafe the **g_p's answer** do the same which my answer do! then what is your problem with this?????

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/9773304/ 
i made the changes like this :-)