# Copying contents of subdirectories in their parent directories

Tags: gnome, bash, scripts

I have a list of jpeg files in a directory like this (below is just a sample, like the structure is the same but this there are many `fo0#` sub-folders, not only `fo01` and `fo02`, where each of these subfolders has many `.jpeg` images, not only two):

```
.
`-- main
    |-- ccc
    |   |-- fo01
    |   |   |-- ccc_fo01_c_000.jpeg
    |   |   `-- ccc_fo01_c_001.jpeg
    |   `-- fo02
    |       |-- ccc_fo02_c_000.jpeg
    |       `-- ccc_fo02_c_001.jpeg
    |-- ddd
    |   |-- fo01
    |   |   |-- ddd_fo01_d_000.jpeg
    |   |   `-- ddd_fo01_d_001.jpeg
    |   `-- fo02
    |       |-- ddd_fo02_d_000.jpeg
    |       `-- ddd_fo02_d_001.jpeg
    `-- lll
        |-- fo01
        |   |-- lll_fo01_l_000.jpeg
        |   `-- lll_fo01_l_001.jpeg
        `-- fo02
            |-- lll_fo02_l_000.jpeg
            `-- lll_fo02_l_001.jpeg
```

What I want to do is to loop on the main directory on each of `ccc`, `ddd` and `lll`, so that in the each iteration of the loop the jpeg images of one of the subfolders will be copied to the parent location. So in the above example, in the first iteration of the loop this will happens:

- `ccc_fo01_c_000.jpeg` and `ccc_fo01_c_001.jpeg` will be copied(not moved) from `ccc/fo01` to `ccc`
- `ddd_fo01_d_000.jpeg` and `ddd_fo01_d_001.jpeg` will be copied(not moved) from `ddd/fo01` to `ddd`
- `lll_fo01_l_000.jpeg` and `lll_fo01_l_001.jpeg` will be copied(not moved) from `lll/fo01` to `lll`

and in the end of the first iteration, those copied jpegs (in `ccc` `ddd` `lll`) will be deleted from `ccc` `ddd` `lll` so that as if I didn't make the copying.

Same with every iteration on the subfolders. So this means that in the above example, the copying then deleting process will happen two times as there are two subfloders `fo01` and `fo02`. But in my case there are more subfolders. So if anyone could please advise how this can be done.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I delete all folders of a specific name without deleting Contents in it?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/574667/how-can-i-delete-all-folders-of-a-specific-name-without-deleting-contents-in-it). Just use `cp` inplace of `mv` command and change the MP#_SONGS to main dir.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a suggestion on how to do it:

First you iterate over the folders, inside every folder you search and find the files and copy them to its parent folder.

```
#!/bin/bash

#Iterate over the folders    
for folder in main/*
do
    #Copy the files into the folder
    find $folder -name "*.jpeg" -type f -exec cp {} $folder \; -print
done

#After its done: delete the originals
find main -mindepth 3 -name "*.jpeg" -type f -delete
```

I just wrote a quick find to delete the files at the end. You could also do this from within the for loop.

Comment: I've tried it but it's not working

Comment: Could you give me a hint as to what went wrong ? You have to run it from the base folder (the one above main).

Comment: this is what happens `bash: /main/ccc: Is a directory`
`find: ``/etc/cups/ssl': Permission denied`
`find:` `/etc/ssl/private': Permission denied` then it kept sending this error message in almost every image in my machine `cp: cannot create regular file ``/home/9278015b02fa780418ef3a5791572af9.jpeg': Permission denied``

Comment: That makes no sense, the for loop uses main/*. Are you sure you didnt add a space separator or something in between the `for folder in main/*`. This error could have been caused if you had like `for folder in main /*` with a space in between.

Comment: this is what I did `location= /media/a/main/ccc` then `for folder in $location/*`

Comment: You should either run the script as-is from your /media/a/main folder or change the for loop to `for folder in /media/a/main/*`. And change the last find to also use /media/a/main: `find /media/a/main -mindepth 3 -name "*.jpeg" -type f -delete`